# navigationController popToViewController not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I want use `popToViewController` of `navigationController` in swift 3.0.

For that I written below code but nothing working as expected.

```
let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
for vc in controllers! {
    if vc is HomeViewController {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I also wrote below code, but that is also working.

```
for vc in controllers! {
    if vc.isKind(of:HomeViewController.self) {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you checked that HomeViewController is actually in the controllers? Try adding a breakpoint to see what the view controllers are at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, HomeViewController was not in hierarchy directly. Actually HomeViewController was integrated in SlideMenu so I need to pop to SlideMenu...

Answer (score 5):

Try this is your code for `popToViewController`

### Swift 3.0

```
  let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
      for vc in controllers! {
        if vc is HomeViewController {
          _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc as! HomeViewController, animated: true)
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 3.1

if you are extension the UINavigationController, make sure you use `self.popToViewController` not `self.navigationController.popToViewController`

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popToViewController<T: UIViewController>(withType type: T.Type) {
         for viewController in self.viewControllers {
             if viewController is T {
               self.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
              return
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is your code for popToViewController

**Update Swift 4.2**

```
let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
         for vc in controllers! {
           if vc is ListViewController {
             _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc as! ListViewController, animated: true)
           }
        }
```